# how to make small loading circle by changing css height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a loading circle but the size is too big and I want to make it smaller but I can't find a way to do that.

I'm using the HTML and CSS below to create the loading circle.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -5px; opacity: 0.25; animation: opacity-60-25-2-13 1s linear infinite;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 10px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 1px; transform-origin: left 50% 0px; transform: rotate(55deg) translate(30px, 0px); border-radius: 5px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
</div>
```

spin.js

```
function SpinStart()
{
    var opts = {
        lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 20, // The length of each line
        width: 10, // The line thickness
        radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
        left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
     spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
}
```

Comment: why cant you use simple gif for spinner instead?

Comment: There is unsufficient html here to generate your "loading circle".  Please supply a jsfiddle

Comment: Have you seen FontAwesome icons? fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples#animated

Comment: Can you post the working fiddle? This code will  not give the loading circle you mentioned

Comment: To use custom HTML and CSS for loading effect you may need to use CSS3 animation as well. But to get it work as in real time you have to apply some JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using spin.js, try changing the option values to  reduce the size of spinner:

```
var opts = {
  lines: 10 // The number of lines to draw
, length: 9 // The length of each line
, width: 5 // The line thickness
, radius: 5 // The radius of the inner circle
, scale: 1 // Scales overall size of the spinner
, corners: 1 // Corner roundness (0..1)
, color: '#000' // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
, opacity: 0.25 // Opacity of the lines
, rotate: 0 // The rotation offset
, direction: 1 // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
, speed: 1 // Rounds per second
, trail: 60 // Afterglow percentage
, fps: 20 // Frames per second when using setTimeout() as a fallback for CSS
, zIndex: 2e9 // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
, className: 'spinner' // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
, top: '50%' // Top position relative to parent
, left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
, shadow: false // Whether to render a shadow
, hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
, position: 'absolute' // Element positioning
}
var target = document.getElementById('spin')
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `transform:scale(0.67)` for the loading circle `div`.It will scale your div small to the original size.

You change scale value according to your requirement.

```
div{
-webkit-transform: scale(0.67);
       -moz-transform: scale(0.67);
            transform: scale(0.67);
}
```

**[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/g2La1ydm/)**

Comment: great thanks but how can I made this change in my js :( in above code ? it will be great help .